# Device not found when setting up android usb debugging in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: android, hp, debugging, adb

I have an HP 10 Plus 2210xx tablet, and I want to use it for Android USB debugging. I followed the following steps:

1. Enabled usb debugging in developers option on phone.
2. After connecting to PC, phone shows as "Usb debugging connected". I
   verified the same by command "lsusb" on Ubuntu 14.10. It shows
   following result:

   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:5d1d Hewlett-Packard
3. Then I followed steps given in https://developer.android.com, to
   setup hardware device.

   Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

   Use this format to add each vendor to the file: SUBSYSTEM=="usb",
   ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

   Now execute: chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
4. After that I rebooted the computer.

   Now when I try to check device list in adb by command "./adb
   devices" , It does not show device listed.

Can anybody please help? Kindly let me know where I am going wrong.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the problem was....

1. Edit ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
2. If the file already exists, add 0x< idVendor> to the end (in my case, this was 0x03f0)
3. adb kill-server
4. adb start-server
5. Check output of adb devices for your device

Device is now listed!